# How asynchronous programming works here?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, nodes

Scenario is as follows:
We have 3 tasks such as T1, T2, T3. T1 is a time consuming process and output of T1 is being utilized in T2. The Order of operation is T1-T2-T3.

As of node.js programming following could be thought of.

T1: fs.readFile(filename, mode, callback); // most expensive computation
T2: get file content from T1 and parse as of certain logic.
T3: Generate report basis of your found content.

Note: I am expecting an answer how to implement asynchronous programming for T1 or it can be done only with synchronous way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may have the option to not read the file at once, but do e.g. line based parsing, and fire up your events after you read a line.

This will likely complicate your logic quite a lot, and it is really dependent on your T2-T3 costs if it is worth the effort. (It would likely only help if T2 and T3 are also somewhat costly, and can be executed on a different thread)